# not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
I followed all the steps from generating a key - updating the key.properties with the typed password,

I added link where the key that was created. but still I have problem so I need the solution

Answer (score 6):

Error you got is caused by incorrect path to keystore. Path to this file is determined by `storeFile` property in `android/key.properties`. It looks like this:

```
storePassword=a
keyPassword=b
keyAlias=c
storeFile=../key.jks
```

Other thing is that this path is not absolute, but relative to `android/app/build.gradle`. To fix your problem place `keystore.jks` inside project folder and reference it using relative path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems gradle gets confused when you use quotes in path like this

```
storePassword=storepwd
keyPassword=mypwd
keyAlias=mykeyname
storeFile='../../../playstore.jks'
```

Removing the quotes fixed it for me.

```
storePassword=storepwd
keyPassword=mypwd
keyAlias=mykeyname
storeFile=../../../playstore.jks
```

Answer (score -1):

check the path of the `keystore.jks` file in the file `key.properties` at the line `storeFile` then try to rebuild release.

```
storePassword=<ur password>
keyPassword=<ur password>
keyAlias=<ur alias>
storeFile=<ur path for keystore.jks>
```